# Permision denied error when I use dofile()

Tags: lua, compiler-errors

```
dofile("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\New folder")
```

My simple code and the error:
**cannot open C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\New folder: Permission denied**

**EDIT: Nevermind sorry about my laziness ;(**

Comment: It seems that you're trying to load a folder as a file.

Comment: What... did you expect to hapen? the function is called *doFILE* for a reason. If you expected it to run all files within the folder, that's not how you do that.